# JAXB override @XmlElement type of list

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, xmladapter

There's a simple class `Bean1` with a sublist of type `BeanChild1`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="bean")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class Bean1
{
  public Bean1()
  {
    super();
  }

  private List<BeanChild1> childList = new ArrayList<>();

  @XmlElement(name="child")
  public List<BeanChild1> getChildList()
  {
    return childList;
  }

  public void setChildList(List<BeanChild1> pChildList)
  {
    childList = pChildList;
  }
}

public static class BeanChild1 { ... }
```

I am trying to override the class, to change the type of the list.
The new child-class (i.e. `BeanChild2`) extends the previous one (i.e. `BeanChild1`) .

```
public static class Bean2 extends Bean1
{
  public Bean2()
  {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  @XmlElement(name="child", type=BeanChild2.class)
  public List<BeanChild1> getChildList()
  {
    return super.getChildList();
  }
}

public static class BeanChild2 extends BeanChild1 { }
```

So, here is how I tested it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String xml = "<bean>" +
               "  <child></child>" +
               "  <child></child>" +
               "  <child></child>" +
               "</bean>";
  Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);

  Bean2 b2 =  JAXB.unmarshal(reader, Bean2.class);
  assert b2.getChildList().get(0) instanceof BeanChild2; // fails
}
```

The test reveals that that this list still contains childs of `BeanChild1`.

**So, how can I force it to populate the `childList` field with `BeanChild2` instances ?**

If there are no easy solutions, then feel free to post more creative solutions (e.g. using `XmlAdapter`s, `Unmarshaller.Listener`, perhaps an additional annotation on the parent or child class ...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change (e.g. override) the `@XmlElement` annotation of a super class. At least not using annotations.

- It doesn't matter what `@XmlAccessorType` you use (e.g. `FIELD`, `PROPERTY`, `PUBLIC`, `NONE`).
- It doesn't make any difference if you put the annotations on the fields or on the getters.

However, there is a reasonable alternative. The MOXy implementation of JAXB offers the ability to [define the metadata/bindings in an xml file](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/solutions/jpatoxml004.htm). In fact every java annotation has an XML alternative. But it gets better: **You can combine both java annotations AND these xml metadata.** The cool thing, is that MOXy will merge both declarations, and in case of conflict, **the XML defined metadata gets a higher priority.**

Assuming that the `Bean1` class is annotated as above. Then it's possible to redefine the binding, in an xml file. e.g.:

```
<xml-bindings xml-accessor-type="PROPERTY">
  <java-types>
    <java-type name="Bean1">
      <xml-element java-attribute="childList" name="child" 
                   type="BeanChild2" container-type="java.util.ArrayList" />
    </java-type>
  </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

This new bindings file is needed during the creation of the context object.

```
// use a map to reference the xml file
Map<String, Object> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
propertyMap.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "bindings.xml");

// pass this properyMap during the creation of the JAXB context.
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(..., propertyMap);
```

MOXy will merge the java annotations and the XML bindings, and in case of a conflict the XML defined settings are applied. In this case, the earlier `@XmlElement(name=child)` annotation is replaced by an xml definition which is equivalent to `@XmlElement(name=child, type=BeanChild2.class)`.

You can read more about the XML bindings [here](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/runtime003.htm).